# Can Johnson take a gamble: refuse to apply for an extension, go to jail and help the Tories win the election and release him?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, boris-johnson

If Johnson refused to apply for an extension and went to jail, he would probably become a "no-deal martyr" for hardline Brexiteers, which would motivate them and increase the chances of no-deal Brexit supporters winning majority in the next election (which is going to happen soon no matter what).

Would such a no-deal supporting parliament have legal means to make the Benn Bill invalid and release Johnson from jail (and make him a PM again)? That would surely be quite a gamble for Johnson, but that's one of the very few scenarios where he wouldn't lose face before his electorate.

Comment: Not sure you should ask "can he", yes he can. What you really want to ask, I assume, is "why would he"

Comment: I'm asking if the parliament has means to release Johnson from jail. If it doesn't, it means Johnson can't take such a gamble, because he has no chances of getting released early and having his sentence cancelled.

Comment: @michau: Consider editing your question to make that clearer. And FWIW, seeing how your second paragraph is phrased, retroactively making something illegal legal so someone doesn't go to jail for it is not how the rule of law works. If it was illegal when it occurred and what you did later becomes legal, you still did something illegal at the time.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy As the answer shows, the parliament would have means to release Johnson, contrary to what you're saying.

Comment: @michau: I wrote the answer. :-) And I stand by the notion that this is not how the rule of law works. But apparently, the legislator may grant amnesty in the UK.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about law.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory he *could* do that. In the UK, [amnesty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amnesty) may be granted by the crown or by an act of Parliament. So for such a scenario to play out, Tories would need to win a general election in short order and pass an appropriate bill or have the PM ask the Queen.

Comment: I can't see them winning an election with their leader in jail and having subverted the law. Also the opposition parties control the election timing at the moment so could just keep him in jail until he gives in.

Comment: @user: Not disagreeing in the slightest. Just answering the OP's hypothetical question.

Comment: In theory, they wouldn't need an Act of Parliament. As you say, a [pardon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_prerogative_of_mercy) can be issued by the Crown, which in practice means at the discretion of the government.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff: I've edited the answer accordingly, since that is technically correct. That said, methinks it would multiply the outrage that would occur compared to if a bill was passed, were either to happen.

Comment: Not to disagree with you, but any outrage might well only be felt by those who voted remain, just saying.

Comment: Also of note: a pardon doesn't quash the conviction. BoJo might become ineligible for office because of the latter, depending exactly what it would be (for).

Comment: @Pelinore: If so, then the UK has a *much* bigger problem on its hands than exiting the EU in whatever form or shape.